# How do i join 3 tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, inner-join

item (**Item_Id**, Item_Name, Category, etc..)

item_details (**Item_Details_Id**, **Item_Id**, Item_Name, Image_path, Price )

item_addon (**Item_Addon_Id**, Item_Name, Category...)

item_detail_addon (**Item_Detail_Addon_Id**, **Item_Details_Id**, **Item_Addon_Id** )

How do i join **item_details** with **item_addon**?

Please note that I am new to sql. Your help will be appreciated

Comment: Search please. This information is _widely_ available.

Comment: Googling MySQL JOIN 3 tables should have given you good hits (in Stack and otherwise); then you could at least try a few things and let us know where you got stuck or didn't get the expected results.

Comment: thanks
SELECT * from Item_detail_addon a 
Inner join Item_details b on a.Item_Details_Id = b.Item_Details_Id
Inner join Item_addon c on a.Item_Addon_Id = c.Item_Addon_Id

I couldnt figure it out, thats why i am here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to join on the common fields you already indentified:

```
SELECT item_details.*
FROM item_details
JOIN item_detail_addon USING(Item_Details_Id)
JOIN item_addon USING(Item_Addon_Id)
```

If some fields on a table have the same name of a field on another table, you can get both by using aliases:

```
SELECT table1.field1 as table1_field1
     , table2.field1 as table2_field1
     [ .. and so on .. ]
```

Comment: Thank you Matteo, however, i am not getting all the fields since some field names are the same in the tables

Comment: See my edit for how to do it!

Comment: Thank you for your help Matteo

SELECT * from Item_detail_addon a 
Inner join Item_details b on a.Item_Details_Id = b.Item_Details_Id
Inner join Item_addon c on a.Item_Addon_Id = c.Item_Addon_Id

Answer (score 1):

Inner Join's are your best bet

```
    select *
    from
        tableA a
            inner join
        tableB b
            on a.common = b.common
            inner join 
        TableC c
            on b.common = c.common
```